# Xcode swift hanging and using 50Gb+ memory only when using iPad symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad

**Edit:** The issue seems to be caused by swift type-checking the vars and going crazy as it doesn't know that the response is an array of arrays. See my comment to get a workaround.

So, I have a swift project, it compiles and runs just fine on the iPhone emulator, but if I switch to the iPad emulator on Xcode (7.3.1), or plug in my iPad 3 (it is up to date), the 'swift' process starts to consume a huge amount of Ram, eventually freezing my computer. If I terminate it, then the SourceKitService does the same... If I then switch back to the iPhone emulator, then everything runs ok, I don't even need to restart Xcode...

Now, I isolated the part of my code where this crash happens:

```
private func startConnection(){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://some.api.com/")
        .responseJSON { response in
            let resposta : NSArray = response.result.value as! NSArray
            // ----- If I remove the comment from the for loop -----
            for i in 0..<resposta.count {
                let canalNovo = Canal()
                canalNovo.novo(resposta[i][0] as! String,
                    nome: resposta[i][4] as! String,
                    desc: resposta[i][5] as! String,
                    src: resposta[i][3] as! String,
                    sigla: resposta[i][1] as! String,
                    corA: resposta[i][2][0] as! String,
                    corB: resposta[i][2][1] as! String,
                    isEnabled: false,
                    updateTime: NSDate()
                )
                self.canais.append(canalNovo)
            }
            // ----- It breaks the compiler... -----

            self.canais = self.canais.shuffle()

            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

As stated in the above comment, if I uncomment the **for** loop, I get a crash, but only if the iPad symbols are being used... I've tried removing the symbols, cleaning dirs on `.../DerivedData`, nothing seems to resolve the problem! Please help me by providing an alternative way of doing this loop, and/or by providing some insight on what may be going wrong it my little app...

Ps.: I tried the for as follows too:

```
            // try One
            let respostaSize = resposta.count - 1

            for i in 0...respostaSize {
                let canalNovo = Canal()
                canalNovo.novo(resposta[i][0] as! String,
                    nome: resposta[i][4] as! String,
                    desc: resposta[i][5] as! String,
                    src: resposta[i][3] as! String,
                    sigla: resposta[i][1] as! String,
                    corA: resposta[i][2][0] as! String,
                    corB: resposta[i][2][1] as! String,
                    isEnabled: false,
                    updateTime: NSDate()
                )
                self.canais.append(canalNovo)
            }

            // try Two
            for canal in resposta {
                let canalNovo = Canal()
                canalNovo.novo(canal[0] as! String,
                    nome: canal[4] as! String,
                    desc: canal[5] as! String,
                    src: canal[3] as! String,
                    sigla: canal[1] as! String,
                    corA: canal[2][0] as! String,
                    corB: canal[2][1] as! String,
                    isEnabled: false,
                    updateTime: NSDate()
                )
                self.canais.append(canalNovo)
            }

            // try Three
            while i < resposta.count {
                let canalNovo = Canal()
                canalNovo.novo(resposta[i][0] as! String,
                    nome: resposta[i][4] as! String,
                    desc: resposta[i][5] as! String,
                    src: resposta[i][3] as! String,
                    sigla: resposta[i][1] as! String,
                    corA: resposta[i][2][0] as! String,
                    corB: resposta[i][2][1] as! String,
                    isEnabled: false,
                    updateTime: NSDate()
                )
                self.canais.append(canalNovo)
                i += 1
            }
```

Still crashes...

Comment: Ok, I figured out a workaround. The issue seems to be caused by swift type-checking the vars and going crazy as it doesn't know that the response is an array of arrays. I corrected it by making the a `Canal` initializer that receives an array as parameter, and then did a foreach parsing the `item as! NSArray` and it did the trick...

I will let the question here for anyone facing the same issue.